# Content の切り替え時にエラーメッセージが消える

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

以下はボタン押下によって ViewA、ViewB に表示を切り替える、というプログラムです。
ViewA、ViewB にそれぞれ必須入力のテキストボックスを追加しています。
（https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/17-BasicRegionNavigation に少し手を加えたものになります）

ViewA、ViewB が最初に表示される時はテキストボックスに赤枠が表示される（エラーになる）のですが、ViewA → ViewB → ViewA と表示した場合には赤枠が表示されません。テキストボックスに何か入力してから空にすると赤枠が表示されるので、必須チェック自体は無くなっていないようですが、表示切替時にのみ赤枠が表示されません。
表示切替時にも赤い枠が表示されるようにするには、どうしたら良いでしょうか。

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="5" >
        <Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="ViewA" Margin="5">Navigate to View A</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="ViewB" Margin="5">Navigate to View B</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" Margin="5"  />
</DockPanel>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; private set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
    }
    private void Navigate(string navigatePath)
    {
        if (navigatePath != null)
            _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", navigatePath);
    }
}
```

**ViewA.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding RequiredText.Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

**ViewB.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding RequiredText.Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

**ViewAViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewAViewModel : BindableBase
{
    [Required]
    public ReactiveProperty<string> RequiredText { get; } = new ReactiveProperty<string>();
    public ViewAViewModel()
    {
        RequiredText.SetValidateAttribute(() => RequiredText);
    }
}
```

**ViewBViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewBViewModel : BindableBase
{
    [Required]
    public ReactiveProperty<string> RequiredText { get; } = new ReactiveProperty<string>();
    public ViewBViewModel()
    {
        RequiredText.SetValidateAttribute(() => RequiredText);
    }
}
```

Comment: 同じ場所で表示を切り替えていることと、データ内容に変化の無いことの組み合わせで発生しているのでは？ 表示を切り替える際にいずれかあるいは両方の状態をリセットするような何かを行えば良いのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 関連するか分かりませんが、何かヒントにでもなれば。[Prism for WPF で非表示となったViewのインスタンスを破棄する設定](https://www.nuits.jp/entry/prism-wpf-remove-with-goback), [WPF How to reset/refresh bound viewmodel when utilizing Prism/Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46108432/9014308), [Wpf Prism Dispose ViewModel after navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46963455/9014308)